# How to click and hold in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a username/password input with a 'show password' button which shows the password text when clicked; but only if you hold it. As soon as you release the click, it will hide the password again.

The wrong way of testing it is:

```
  it('show password word', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="login-password-input"]').should('have.type', 'password')
    cy.get('[data-cy="show-password-btn"]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy="login-password-input"]').should('have.type', 'text')
  })
```

Since this reverts back to type=password before I have a chance to check it. Is it possible to keep the click held down whilst performing the last verification check?

Answer (score 2):

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="show-password-btn"]').trigger('mousedown', {
  button: 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{release:false}
```

can be added.
See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Key-Combinations for reference

Comment: Didn't work for me :( , I am trying create an automated lasso on marker on the map

Answer (score 0):

It works:

`cy.get("@element").trigger("mousedown");`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event